# KDE plasma using too much memory

Tags: kubuntu, plasma, kde5, memory-leak

I use Kubuntu 18.04. When I use it for a long time, opening and closing many applications, the memory usage goes up to 3gb and never comes down after closing all open applications. This issue is more likely to happen after copying a lot of files. In htop, I can see about 10 processes with name plasmashell, using the highest memory. How can I fix this memory leak? (I'm a noob)

Comment: Read `man htop` or https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man1/htop.1.html `htop` will let you kill processes.

Comment: After killing, some parts of the desktop became unresponsive, so I restarted from tty

Comment: It's only a temporary fix. I will have to restart everytime this happens